# Git Push Tag for Multi Branch Pipeline

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, git-tag

I am using the below code:

```
  sshagent(['creds_ssh'])
     {
         sh("""
             git tag -l
             git tag -a ${tagNm} -m "git tag ${tagNm}"
             git push origin ${tagNm}
         """)
     }
```

And this works perfectly for normal pipeline jobs. After the commit, it tags the commit & pushes the tag. However, using the same code for multi-branch pipeline fails with error

```
fatal: Failed to resolve 'HEAD' as a valid ref.
```

Is this some known limitation for multi-branch jenkins pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

I did figure out a way to push git tags in the Jenkinsfile for a Multibranch Pipeline.

If you're using GitHub as the option in the multibranch pipeline you can't use sshagent since the URL is restricted to HTTPS.

That means we need to interact with git in the pipeline using HTTPS URLs.

We'll need your GitHub username and password as a Jenkins credentia. Once you've done that you can reference the credential.

I set my env.VERSION higher in the pipeline file.

```
steps {
            withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'your-github-username-and-password-cred-id', usernameVariable: 'ACCESS_TOKEN_USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'ACCESS_TOKEN_PASSWORD')]) {
                sh('git checkout master')
                sh("git pull https://${ACCESS_TOKEN_USERNAME}:${ACCESS_TOKEN_PASSWORD}@github.com/repo_url.git master")
                sh("git tag ${env.VERSION}")
                sh("git push https://${ACCESS_TOKEN_USERNAME}:${ACCESS_TOKEN_PASSWORD}@github.com/repo_url.git ${env.VERSION}")
            }
        }
```